# DRF custom serializer "Field name is not valid for model"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a big model that I'd like to reduce to just a name and its ID. My (relevant) code is as follows:

```py
### Models
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

class Employee(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField('Person', related_name='employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Job(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee')

### Serializers
class SimpleEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        name = instance.person.first_name + ' ' + instance.person.last_name
        return {
            'id': instance.id,
            'name': name,
        }

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        try:
            try:
                obj_id = data['id']
                return Employee.objects.get(id=obj_id)
            except KeyError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id is a required field.'
                )
            except ValueError:
                raise serializers.ValidationError(
                    'id must be an integer.'
                )
        except Employee.DoesNotExist:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'Obj does not exist.'
            )

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ['id', 'name']

class JobSerializer(WritableNestedModelSerializer):
    employee = SimpleEmployeeSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = MpProject
        fields = [
            'id',
            'employee',
        ]
```

Please do not concern yourself with whether this should or should not be a OneToOne relation, my model is more complicated in practice.

The error I'm getting is `ImproperlyConfigured: Field name 'name' is not valid for model 'Employee'.` I didn't get this error when I had not implemented `to_internal_value`, but I need this since I want to be able to POST a new `Job` with the `SimpleEmployee` format. Can someone tell me why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of `fields`

```
class Meta:
    model = Employee
    fields = ['id', 'name'] # <- this line
```

You might be able to fix this by adding a field:

```
class SimpleEmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=False) # Maybe add read_only or write_only depending on usage.
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixed my initial error, but now I'm getting another one... Do you happen to know how to fix that one too? It's at the url `/jobs/` and the error is `TypeError: 'Employee' object is not a mapping`.

Comment: also just an aside, if you set 

serializers.CharField(required=False)

and the serialize type doesnt match the data type stored in the DB it wont render, but it also won't complain. So beware of that.